# roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run roscd i got this error ????

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

update

```
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash 
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make 
Base path: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/ahmed/catkin_ws/build"
####
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ roscd beginner_tutorials
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

new update i tried roscd profile and this the result

```
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.021956 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,
re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.021130   /opt/ros/kinetic/share
0.000162 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.2.0-dev
0.000036 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.2.0-dev/haarcascades
0.000031 * /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src
0.000029 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc
0.000013 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.2.0-dev/lbpcascades
0.000006 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ ~/.ros/rospack_cache*
bash: /home/ahmed/.ros/rospack_cache_10864520700894273605: Permission denied
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271053/roscd:-no-such-package/stack-%27beginner_tutorials%27/) by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-09-16**:
Assuming that you have installed the package `beginner_tutorials`, try going to your catkin workspace, for example `~/catkin_ws` and running `source devel/setup.bash` from the command line.

**Comment by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on 2017-09-17**:
Thanx for reply but i tried this solution and it is not work for me

```
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ roscd beginner_tutorials
roscd: No such package/stack 'beginner_tutorials'
```

**Comment by [surfertas](https://answers.ros.org/users/27828/surfertas/) on 2017-09-17**:
Can I confirm that you have created the package and ran the commands to build the package as well before sourcing?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-19**:
Have you tried compiling first then `source`ing the `setup.bash`?

**Comment by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on 2017-09-19**:
could you tell me the command to make compile

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-19**:
`catkin_make`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome! This question comes up quite often. A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=roscd%3A+No+such+package%2Fstack+site%3Aanswers.ros.org) will give you numerous results:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/65003/roscd-no-such-packagestack-beginner_tutorials/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/65950/roscd-returns-roscd-no-such-packagestack-package_name/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/239650/roscd-not-woring/

This is just to name the first few results.

---

**Edit:**

I noticed that you're `source`ing your `setup.bash` before you compile. Try doing it in this order:

```
~/catkin_ws/$ catkin_make
~/catkin_ws/$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

**Edit 2:**

As @jarvisschultz pointed out in the comments:

> [`rospack` uses a cache](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospack.html#efficiency-considerations) of all available packages. This caches is, in turn, used by tools like `roscd`. This cache is supposed to be re-built every 60 seconds by default, but sometimes it seems like this fails.
> You could force a re-build with `rospack profile` or you could try removing the cache files in `~/.ros/rospack_cache*`. Both of these have helped me in the past when packages couldn't be picked up even though the environment vars were correct.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on 2017-09-17**:
thanx but it doesnot work for me

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-17**:
Do you have a package with that name? Did you `catkin_make` it from the root of your workspace? Did you `source` the `setup.bash`? What have you done and what was the result?

**Comment by [ahmedadelhekal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31934/ahmedadelhekal/) on 2017-09-17**:
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
ahmed@ahmed-HP-Casablanca-H510:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ahmed/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-17**:
Can you please update your question with that information? It looks like it got cut off due to character count limitations.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-09-18**:
[rospack uses a cache](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/rospack.html#efficiency-considerations) of all available packages. This caches is, in turn, used by tools like `roscd`. This cache is supposed to be re-built every 60 seconds by default, but sometimes it seems like this fails.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-09-18**:
You could force a re-build with `rospack profile` or you could try removing the cache files in `~/.ros/rospack_cache*`. Both of these have helped me in the past when packages couldn't be picked up even though the environment vars were correct.